# open a file and wait for it to quit/exit then continue batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
    SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    ::  change your Given/First name
    set MYSELF=Felipe
    set BOSS=Jon
    set "MYFILE=Timesheet_%MYSELF%_FY10.11_Version_1.1.xls"
    set "MYLOCKEDFILE=%MYFILE%.gpg"
    set "SAFETY=~%MYFILE%"

    ::  PFx86: this variable is needed to avoid breaking 'if' statement below
    set "PFx86=%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%"
    if exist (%PFx86%) (
        set "GPGBIN=%PFx86%\GNU\GnuPG\"
        echo 64-bit windows...
    ) else (
        set "GPGBIN=%PROGRAMFILES%\GNU\GnuPG\"
        echo 32-bit windows...
    )

    if exist %MYLOCKEDFILE% (
        echo locked file found
        for %%F in (%MYLOCKEDFILE%) do (
            set ATTRIBS=%%~aF
            set READ_ATTRIB=!ATTRIBS:~1,1!

            if !READ_ATTRIB!==r (
                echo locked file is RO...
                ::  svn lock
                TortoiseProc.exe /command:lock /path:%MYLOCKEDFILE%
            ) else (
                echo locked file is RW...
            )

            ::  decrypt
            echo decrypting...
            "%GPGBIN%\gpg.exe" "%MYLOCKEDFILE%"
        )

        if exist %MYFILE% (
            echo opening %MYFILE%...
            %MYFILE%
            echo encrypting...
            ::  encrypt
            gpg.exe -r %BOSS% -r %MYSELF% -e %MYFILE%
            echo deleting %MYFILE%...
            del %MYFILE%
        )
    )
```

I have a batch file that does the following

1. decrypts a timesheet.xls.gpg file
2. opens it with

   "timesheet.xls"
3. then encrypts it again with gpg

When the timesheet gets opened, it immediately continues to the 'encrypt' phase.

How can I make it wait until the XLS file is closed to resume the running of the script (without explicit user intervention)?

Comment: Did you try `START /WAIT %MYFILE%`?

Comment: yes. I discovered the START command a while after posting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used

```
START /WAIT "title" "..\path\to\excel.exe" "%MYFILE%"
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off forgetting about using a batch file for this and instead use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), which can wait until the opening of the spreadsheet is finished by Excel and then continue on from there to the encryption phase.

To quote from their page:

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or reliable with other languages (e.g. VBScript and SendKeys). AutoIt is also very small, self-contained and will run on all versions of Windows out-of-the-box with no annoying “runtimes” required!

This will be a better fit for the task at hand.